# Как изменять переменную Vue js и вне?

Tags: vue.js

Как изменять переменную Vue js и вне? Пробовал так:

```js
<script>
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                newstext: "Loading"
            }
        },
        methods: {
        },
        components: {
            navbar,
            mapss,
            mm,
        },
    }
function b() {
  this.newstext = "Notload"
 }
</scrit>
```

Но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Засунь "вне" внутрь

Comment: Вообще это плохо, менять значение чего либо из фреймворка вне фремворка... Потом может быть что угодно непредвиденное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Засунь "вне" внутрь. Например в плагин.

Но если очень хочется, то можно через замыкание в лямбде.

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            newstext: "Loading"
        }
    },
    methods: {
       setnewstext(text) {
          this.newstext = text
       }
    },
    components: {
        navbar,
        mapss,
        mm,
    },
    mounted() {
        let self = this;
        window.setnewstext = (text) => {self.setnewstext(text)}
    }
}

function b() {
  setnewstext("Notload")
}
</scrit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменение состояние Vue из "вне" противоречит философии и стандартам "хорошего кода" Vue. Как вам написал "eri" - лучший способ изменить переменную Vue - изменить её внутри самого Vue и для этого необходим Vuex.

Vuex - это пожалуй лучший и самый безопасный (без сюрпризов) способ изменить переменную Vue вне компонента Vue. Vuex - это хранилище Vue, создано для обмена информацией между компонентами и для ситуаций как у Вас.

Есть ещё варианты с костылями, к примеру: [тык](https://codesandbox.io/embed/qna-q952763-1d7b6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) (нагуглил ещё десяток, погуглите) и, возможно поможет Vue метод `watch`, но я не знаю конкретно что Вам нужно, по этому вероятно `watch` не решит Вашу проблему. Опять же, лучше всего смотрите в сторону Vuex и изменяйте переменные Vue через него.

Comment: Напишите пример как достучаться к vuex  из вне

Comment: @eri к примеру вот: https://codepen.io/arhey/pen/pXBxMW
В целом использование Vuex без Vue не отличается кардинально.

Comment: но тут new VuexStore, а не подключение к внутреннему Vue.